# SSL Communication Java

Tags: java, security, ssl

I have generated self-signed certificates for an `admin` instance of my app and a `judge` instance of my app. These instances are running on different machines and they both have copies of each others certificates and their own. I want to communicate between these two, and I am wondering whether my current approach is the correct way to do so:

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
Certificate certificate = cf.generateCertificate(new FileInputStream(...));

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(null, "test".toCharArray());
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("admin", certificate);

// Code omitted which repeats the above to set the judge certificate

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(keyStore);
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ctx.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

factory = ctx.getSocketFactory(); // Or #getServerSocketFactory() if admin and not judge
```

With this I will be able to securely communicate with the two instances, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The KeyManager needs a keystore with a key entry, not a certificate entry. Just use keystore files as intended by the designers of JSSE.

Comment: Okay, I did that, but there seems to be a problem. I am running two threads which have a ServerSocket and a Socket. I use the correct keystore file on the ServerSocket, and a blank one on Socket, yet I am still able to connect. Shouldn't the connection be rejected?

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee The `SSLSocket` only needs a keystore if the `SSLServerSocket` is set up to require client authentication. It does always need a truststore. I think you need to have a good look at the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html).